# SQL - Get the MAX COUNT access peak having only entrance and exit date

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a table that keeps the access to our system, and it have two columns called entranceTime and exitTime

Eg:

```
entranceTime            exitTime
2021-09-09 20:03:31+00  2021-09-09 20:05:39+00
2021-09-09 20:03:58+00  2021-09-09 20:05:11+00
2021-09-09 20:04:29+00  2021-09-09 20:05:36+00
2021-09-09 20:04:09+00  2021-09-09 20:04:28+00
2021-09-09 20:05:15+00  2021-09-09 20:05:30+00
```

What im trying to get is the "peak" of simultaneous connections, i tried using a subquery
with MAX and COUNT like this:

```
SELECT Max((SELECT Count("a"."id")
            FROM   "public"."access" "a"
            WHERE  "a"."entrancetime" >= "a2"."entrancetime"
                   AND a."entrancetime" <= "a2"."exittime"))
FROM   "public"."access" a2
```

But with this query im getting the count of 5 instad of 3, is it possible to achieve this with only this two columns and using only SQL? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "peak" is going to occur at one of the entrance times.  You can use a correlated subquery to count the number of concurrent rows at each one.  And then get the peak:

```
select max(num_concurrent)
from (select a.*,
             (select count(*)
              from "public"."access" a2
              where a2.exittime >= a.entrancetime and
                    a2.entrancetime <= a.entrancetime
             ) as num_concurrent
      from "public"."access" a
     ) a;
```

The above may not scale well, so there is actually a more efficient way.  You can unpivot the times and use cumulative sums:

```
select v.t, sum(v.inc) as net_inc,
       sum(sum(v.inc)) over (order by v.t) as num_concurrent
from "public"."access" a cross join lateral
     (values (a.entrancetime, 1), (a.exittime, -1)
     ) v(t, inc)
group by v.t
order by num_concurrent desc
limit 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0a4dd7c8d8097148fcf9dcc4eaeaece4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: The first query worked like a charm, but the second one is returning max = 5

Comment: @MatheusHatje . . . I fixed the first query and added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison was a bit off, see modification below with example fiddle

```sql
SELECT MAX((SELECT Count("a"."entranceTime")
            FROM   "public"."access_times" "a"
            WHERE  "a2"."entranceTime" >= "a"."entranceTime"
                   AND "a2"."entranceTime" <= "a"."exitTime"))
            
FROM   "public"."access_times" a2
```

[View live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ueGnfYR7prFAqhQ948zomD/1)

also the following example uses an inner join to determine overlapping times for entrance times and finally uses the `max` to determine the peak time of this subquery.

**Subquery identifying overlapping times**

```
SELECT 
        "a"."entranceTime",Count(1) as cnt
    FROM   
        "public"."access_times" "a"
    INNER JOIN
        "public"."access_times" "a2"
            ON  "a"."entranceTime" >= "a2"."entranceTime"
             AND a."entranceTime" <= "a2"."exitTime"
    GROUP BY "a"."entranceTime";
```

| entranceTime | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-09T20:03:58.000Z | 2 |
| 2021-09-09T20:03:31.000Z | 1 |
| 2021-09-09T20:05:15.000Z | 3 |
| 2021-09-09T20:04:29.000Z | 3 |
| 2021-09-09T20:04:09.000Z | 3 |

---

**One approach to retrieving number of overlaps**

```
SELECT 
    MAX(cnt) as peak 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Count(1) as cnt
    FROM   
        "public"."access_times" "a"
    INNER JOIN
        "public"."access_times" "a2"
            ON  "a"."entranceTime" >= "a2"."entranceTime"
             AND a."entranceTime" <= "a2"."exitTime"
    GROUP BY "a"."entranceTime"
) t;
```

| peak |
| --- |
| 3 |

---

**Retrieving peak time with number of overlaps**

```
SELECT 
        "a"."entranceTime" as peak_time,Count(1) as no_occurrences
    FROM   
        "public"."access_times" "a"
    INNER JOIN
        "public"."access_times" "a2"
            ON  "a"."entranceTime" >= "a2"."entranceTime"
             AND a."entranceTime" <= "a2"."exitTime"
    GROUP BY "a"."entranceTime"
    ORDER BY Count(1) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

| peak_time | no_occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-09-09T20:05:15.000Z | 3 |

---

```
SELECT 
        Count(1) as no_occurrences
    FROM   
        "public"."access_times" "a"
    INNER JOIN
        "public"."access_times" "a2"
            ON  "a"."entranceTime" >= "a2"."entranceTime"
             AND a."entranceTime" <= "a2"."exitTime"
    GROUP BY "a"."entranceTime"
    ORDER BY Count(1) DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

| no_occurrences |
| --- |
| 3 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ueGnfYR7prFAqhQ948zomD/3)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @matheus-hatje I updated my answer to address the logic error in your attempt. Let me know if this works for you